# Forcing other persons files to checkin using Sourcesafe 2005

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

One of my colleagues has left the company and taken his PC with him!

Some of his work is checked-out.

Is there a way I can check-in his work without access to his PC?

This is using Sourcesafe 2005.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get his updates back - they have gone with his PC*.

You can use VSS admin to undo his checkouts so that you can carry on working with the files.

*Unless you have backups.

Answer (score 4):

You can, from the VSS admin, reset his password. After that, you can login with is account and "check in" or undo check out of the file. But please understand that this doesn't mean that VSS will automagically fetch the work he has done from his PC...

Answer (score 2):

No.  The only thing you can do, is revert back to the latest checked-in file.

Answer (score 2):

No, as the modified files would only exist on his PC - to which you don't have access.

The only way you could recover the edits (other than asking your colleague to return what presumably is company property) is if you were backing up your edits to the server as well.

We did this at one company we worked at as a precaution against theft.

Again, as the others have pointed out, you can cancel the check out via the admin options.

Comment: Can you explain how this is done?  Edits are automatically cached somehow?

Comment: No - we ran scheduled tasks on local PCs to backup project files to the server

Answer (score 1):

You can very well do it by going to the VSS server. In VSS Server open VSS admin console. There you can reset that persons password. Then open VSS client and login with his user name and password. Then you will be able to do anything !!!